# How can I put an equation and an image in the same row? (Latex)

Tags: latex

I want to put an equation with cases on the left and its graph on the right, in the same row. I try with different solutions I found on stackoverflow, but any of them could help me. This is the code I wrote in VSC:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Finestra rettangolare e area unitaria:}
      \begin{tabular}{c c}
          \begin{equation*} \Pi(t) =
              \begin{cases}
                  1, & -\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq -\frac{1}{2} \\
                  0, & altrove                               \\
              \end{cases}
          \end{equation*} 
          & 
          \includegraphics[scale=0.1]{Rectangular_Function_C.png}
      \end{tabular}
```

But it doesn't work:
[image]
[Function image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4L18.png)

Comment: Please add a compilable [mre], not just a code fragment

Comment: Did you test the code in your question? There is not document environment, the itemize never closes ... also please don't add back the vs code tag. Your editor isn't relevant for a question about your latex code. I already removed it yesterday and today another user had to do the same, again :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't use an equation inside a table cell. You can use inline math like `$...$` instead
- to vertically align the image with the equation, you can use the `valign=m` key from the `adjustbox` package
- you shouldn't set multi-letter words in math mode, the kerning will be all wrong. Instead you can use `\text{altrove}`

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, color}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[thinc]{esdiff}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Finestra rettangolare e area unitaria:}

      \begin{tabular}{c c}
          $\displaystyle\Pi(t) =
              \begin{cases}
                  1, & -\frac{1}{2} \leq t \leq -\frac{1}{2} \\
                  0, & \text{altrove}                               \\
              \end{cases}
          $
          & 
          \includegraphics[width=3cm,valign=m]{example-image-duck}
      \end{tabular}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]